# set date format for new Date().toLocaleString()

Tags: javascript, vue.js, date, time

I am using

`new Date().toLocaleString()`

to get the current date and time. The format in which I am getting the date and time is

`4_20_2021, 12_37_15 PM`

but the required format is

`MM/DD/YYY, HH:MM:SS AM/PM`

Please help me achieve this. I am using this in my vue app.

Update 1

I am using moment.js to get the current date and time and I am trying to format it in the following format

```
'MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'
```

But the issue here is that the separation between hours, minutes and seconds is showing as underscore instead of colons. This is the how I am implementing it.

```
downloadCSV() {
  var url = OFFERS_URL + '?';
  this.$axios.get(url, responseType: 'blob' })
  .then(response => {
    var file = new Blob([response.data]);
    FileSaver.saveAs(file, 'Offers ' + moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a') + '.xls');
  });
}
```

The downloaded file name showes as

```
Offers April 20th 2021, 1_26_59 PM
```

but it should be

```
Offers April 20th 2021, 1:26:59 PM
```

Comment: [Check here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) i think you missed something.

Comment: that would be a weird locale, but toLocaleString() can vary between browsers and countries so if you require a specific format you need to construct it yourself (or use something like moment.js)

Comment: @GarrGodfrey I have updated the question, I am using moment.js now, but there is this small is with hh:mm:ss separation as stated in Update 1 in the question.

Answer (score -2):

*if you use this,  then you get your expected result.. The vanila javascript  format is same to your format*`setInterval(()=>{ var date=new Date().toLocaleDateString();var time= new Date().toLocaleTimeString(); console.log(date,time) },1000)`